# c# Interface method must have return type that derives from itself

Tags: c#, .net, types, .net-4.5

I'm looking for a valid way of doing something like this pseudo code.

```
public interface INormalizedObject{
    void someMethodThatHappensToNormalizedObjects();
    T NormalizeObject(T obj) where T : derives from INormalizedObject;
}
```

specifically, how do I put a type constraint on the interface that the method NormalizeObject returns an object of type base INormalizedObject?

Comment: Instead of `T`, use `INormalizedObject`. It's not clear to me what you're asking. Do you mean that the method `NormalizeObject` has to return the actual type that implements the interface?

Comment: There's a lot of questions in one here, really. Using a generic type is simple (just use `T` instead of `<T>`), the generic constraint is also simple (`where T: INormalizedObject`), but `this` can only be used for static extension methods - if you need the method to be polymorphic, define a generic interface instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want `T` to mean "the type that implements this interface", you can make the interface generic:

```
public interface INormalizedObject<T> 
   where T : INormalizedObject<T>
{
    T NormalizeObject(T obj);
}
```

Then implement it:

```
public class Foo : INormalizedObject<Foo>
{
    public Foo NormalizeObject(Foo obj)
    {
    }
}
```

But what you *actually* seem to be asking for is simply this:

```
public interface INormalizedObject
{
    INormalizedObject NormalizeObject(INormalizedObject obj);
}
```

Because that's all your code should need to know.

Comment: He cannot enforce that the `<Foo>` part actually references the same class that is implementing the interface. This is legal code: `public class Foo : INormalizedObject<Bar>`.

Comment: @Lasse of course. Is there a way to enforce `T` to be `Foo` there?

Comment: No, not at all. I just feel that this is what the OP wanted, but he cannot get that part. Other than that your approach is the best way I feel.

Comment: @Lasse that will be caused by the principle that the interface has no notion of the type that implements it, so it cannot have a "back-reference" to it unless you specify it - and you'll have to do so carefully, as you noticed. Thanks for your addition.

Comment: Would either of you know of a way of implementing it so by writing
public class  Foo : INormalizedObject
is the same as instantiating T as the type of the class that is implementing it? 
eg public class Foo : INormalizedObject<Foo> without writing the last <Foo>?

Comment: @Chad no, like I said, the interface doesn't know what type implements it, so it cannot enforce that. Also see edit, you actually shouldn't need that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use the word this here, as it would require your method to be static.
Could you try this

```
    public interface INormalizedObject
    {
     void someMethodThatHappensToNormalizedObjects();
     T NormalizeObject<T>(T obj) where T : INormalizedObject;
    }
```